# Simple angular project not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

can't seem to get the test.json data to output on my local.

Not sure if it's to do with the fact I'm running it locally or not.

Thanks :)

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body ng-app="testApp">

    <div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
        <div class="container">
            <div ng-repeat="info in test">
                <p>{{ info.nm }}</p>
                <p>{{ info.cty }}</p>
                <p>{{ info.hse }}</p>
                <img ng-src="{{ info.cty }}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Include the AngularJS library -->
    <script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Modules -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>

    <!-- Services -->
    <script src="js/services/servicetest.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', ['']);
```

MainController.js

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'test', function($scope, test) {
  test.success(function(data) {
    $scope.test = data;
  });
}]);
```

servicetest.js

```
app.factory('test', ['$http', function($http) {
  return $http.get('test.json')
            .success(function(data) {
              return data;
            })
            .error(function(err) {
              return err;
            });
}]);
```

test.json is in the same folder as servicetest.js.

Comment: Can you provide the error that pops in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Several mistakes are there in your code.

1. You should not specify module dependency as blank(`''`) which would ask injector for `''` and will throw an `$injector error`

   ```
    var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
   ```
2. Factory should return a object of methods like

   ```
   app.factory('test', ['$http', function($http) {
     var getData = function(){
        return $http.get('test.json')
     }
     return {
       getData: getData
     }
   }]);
   ```
3. Utilize newly created factory method from controller.

   ```
    test.getData().then(function(response) {
       $scope.test = response.data;
    });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
```

instead of

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', ['']);
```

That array is meant, You could simply say for injecting various dependency.